# SQL Server : how to loop through rows and assign value

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a couple of tables to deal with. One is like this:

**dbo.userActivity**

```
 userID    Action    Time
   1         25       12:00
   1         10       12:01
   1         12       12:35
   1          6       13:54
   2         10        6:47
   2         42        6:48
   3          8       11:54
   etc.
```

The other table is a schedule that looks like this:

**dbo.userSchedule**

```
 userID    schedule_start    schedule_stop
   1            07:00            09:00
   2            11:00            12:30
   3            14:00            15:00
  etc.
```

What I need to do for each row in `dbo.userActivity` is determine if each action was an hour before the `schedule_start`, between the `schedule_start` and `schedule_stop` times, an hour after `schedule_stop`, or any other time.

So I need to append a column to `dbo.userActivity` with the values 'before', 'during', 'after', 'other' based on the time calculations.

I'm really not sure how to do this and would appreciate any help you all could offer.

EDIT:

Okay, so I have that mostly working. I've just seen some of the real data I'll be working on and noticed that the activity times are full datetime stamps, whereas the activity schedule is just in time. So I need to convert the datetime to something I can compare.

This looks like it works:

> SELECT * 
>   FROM
>     (
>         SELECT CONVERT(TIME, SCANDATE) as scanTime 
>         FROM appData
>     ) st
>   WHERE st.scanTime <= '6:00'
>   ORDER BY st.scanTime

Just as an example. But when I try to incorporate that into the case statement below like this, it doesn't work. It applies the same THEN to every row.

> ```
> SELECT
>   CASE
>   WHEN EXISTS
>   (
>   SELECT *
>   FROM
>   (
>   SELECT CONVERT(TIME, SCANDATE) as scanTime 
>   FROM appData
>   ) st
>   WHERE st.scanTime <= '6:00'
>   )
>   THEN 'Before 6 am'
>
>   ELSE '6 am or after'
>   END
> FROM appData
> ```

Any further thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would want to add the column (`NULL`) to your table.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.UserActivity
ADD TimeStatus VARCHAR(6) NULL;
```

Next you would write your update query.  It can be written with a `CASE` statement:

```
UPDATE ua
SET ua.TimeStatus =
   CASE
      WHEN CAST(ua.Time AS TIME) >= us.Schedule_Start
         AND CAST(ua.Time AS TIME) <= us.Schedule_stop THEN 'During'
      WHEN CAST(ua.Time AS TIME) >= DATEADD(HOUR, -1, us.Schedule_Start)
         AND CAST(ua.Time AS TIME) <= us.ScheduleStart THEN 'Before'
      WHEN CAST(ua.Time AS TIME) >= us.Schedule_Stop
         AND CAST(ua.Time AS TIME) <= DATEADD(HOUR, 1, us.Schedule_Stop)
         THEN 'After'
      ELSE 'Other'
   END
FROM dbo.UserActivity AS ua
INNER JOIN dbo.userSchedule AS us ON ua.UserId = us.UserId
```

Once all the columns have data, you can set the column to `NOT NULL` if you have updated the application to know about, and populate, this new column.

---

I would also consider not storing the string values in this table, but instead a smaller value that will foreign key to a reference table instead.  With only 4 values, you can use a `TINYINT` and save space for each dbo.UserActivity record that you store.

If you decide to go this route, you would just take the values from the reference table, and replace the string values with the ID values.  If Before = 0, during = 1, After = 2, and Other = 3

```
UPDATE ua
SET ua.TimeStatusId =
   CASE
      WHEN CAST(ua.Time AS TIME) >= us.Schedule_Start
         AND CAST(ua.Time AS TIME) <= us.Schedule_stop THEN 1
      WHEN CAST(ua.Time AS TIME) >= DATEADD(HOUR, -1, us.Schedule_Start)
         AND CAST(ua.Time AS TIME) <= us.ScheduleStart THEN 0
      WHEN CAST(ua.Time AS TIME) >= us.Schedule_Stop
         AND CAST(ua.Time AS TIME) <= DATEADD(HOUR, 1, us.Schedule_Stop)
         THEN 2
      ELSE 3
   END
FROM dbo.UserActivity AS ua
INNER JOIN dbo.userSchedule AS us ON ua.UserId = us.UserId
```

You would then get the text values for the UI with an `INNER JOIN` to your TimeStatus reference table

Comment: @AndrewMartin I updated the `CASE` to use `CAST(ua.Time AS TIME)` which worked in a simple test I conducted.  Please let me know if you run into any other issues.

Comment: That does the trick. A lot simpler too, than what I was trying. Thanks again.

Comment: I have an addition problem now. Now it's possible for people to have multiple start and stop times throughout the day. Up to five, but different people will have only one, but others will have 2 or 3. I suspect I need to account for that using NOT NULL or COALESCE in the case statements. Any thoughts about how that might work?

Comment: @AndrewMartin It sounds like this is a separate issue.  It may be easier if you create another question for this new issue (userSchedule having multiple schedules for one user).  Since this was not part of the original question, I did not account for it.  A new question would allow myself, and other people to only see the relevant issue you are currently experiencing, and not be distracted by the original work done here.